# pylint error 'TreeRebuilder3k' object has no attribute 'visit_joinedstr' when import functools

Tags: python-3.x, pylint

With single line `t.py` containing

```
import functools
```

pylint gives error

```
AttributeError: 'TreeRebuilder3k' object has no attribute 'visit_joinedstr'
```

Is there a workaround?

Version info:

```
$ pylint --version
No config file found, using default configuration
pylint 1.6.5, 
astroid 1.4.9
Python 3.6.1 (default, Mar 21 2017, 21:49:16) 
[GCC 5.4.0]
```

complete error with long Traceback:

```
$ pylint t.py 
No config file found, using default configuration
************* Module t
C:  1, 0: Missing module docstring (missing-docstring)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pylint", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(run_pylint())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pylint/__init__.py", line 17, in run_pylint
    Run(sys.argv[1:])
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pylint/lint.py", line 1333, in __init__
    linter.check(args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pylint/lint.py", line 755, in check
    self._do_check(files_or_modules)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pylint/lint.py", line 886, in _do_check
    self.check_astroid_module(ast_node, walker, rawcheckers, tokencheckers)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pylint/lint.py", line 967, in check_astroid_module
    walker.walk(ast_node)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pylint/utils.py", line 959, in walk
    self.walk(child)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pylint/utils.py", line 956, in walk
    cb(astroid)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pylint/checkers/variables.py", line 1051, in visit_import
    module = next(node.infer_name_module(parts[0]))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/astroid/context.py", line 49, in cache_generator
    for result in generator:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/astroid/bases.py", line 302, in wrapped
    for res in _func(node, context, **kwargs):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/astroid/inference.py", line 123, in infer_import
    yield self.do_import_module(name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/astroid/mixins.py", line 129, in do_import_module
    relative_only=level and level >= 1)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/astroid/scoped_nodes.py", line 492, in import_module
    return MANAGER.ast_from_module_name(absmodname)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/astroid/manager.py", line 136, in ast_from_module_name
    return self.ast_from_file(filepath, modname, fallback=False)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/astroid/manager.py", line 86, in ast_from_file
    return AstroidBuilder(self).file_build(filepath, modname)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/astroid/builder.py", line 141, in file_build
    module = self._data_build(data, modname, path)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/astroid/builder.py", line 185, in _data_build
    module = builder.visit_module(node, modname, node_file, package)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/astroid/rebuilder.py", line 154, in visit_module
    newnode.body = [self.visit(child, newnode) for child in node.body]
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/astroid/rebuilder.py", line 154, in <listcomp>
    newnode.body = [self.visit(child, newnode) for child in node.body]
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/astroid/rebuilder.py", line 167, in visit
    return visit_method(node, parent, assign_ctx)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/astroid/rebuilder.py", line 957, in visit_classdef
    newnode = super(TreeRebuilder3k, self).visit_classdef(node, parent, assign_ctx)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/astroid/rebuilder.py", line 357, in visit_classdef
    for child in node.body]
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/astroid/rebuilder.py", line 357, in <listcomp>
    for child in node.body]
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/astroid/rebuilder.py", line 167, in visit
    return visit_method(node, parent, assign_ctx)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/astroid/rebuilder.py", line 543, in visit_functiondef
    assign_ctx=assign_ctx)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/astroid/rebuilder.py", line 528, in _visit_functiondef
    for child in node.body]
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/astroid/rebuilder.py", line 528, in <listcomp>
    for child in node.body]
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/astroid/rebuilder.py", line 167, in visit
    return visit_method(node, parent, assign_ctx)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/astroid/rebuilder.py", line 447, in visit_expr
    newnode.value = self.visit(node.value, newnode, assign_ctx)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/astroid/rebuilder.py", line 167, in visit
    return visit_method(node, parent, assign_ctx)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/astroid/rebuilder.py", line 315, in visit_call
    for child in node.args]
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/astroid/rebuilder.py", line 315, in <listcomp>
    for child in node.args]
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/astroid/rebuilder.py", line 167, in visit
    return visit_method(node, parent, assign_ctx)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/astroid/rebuilder.py", line 549, in visit_generatorexp
    newnode.elt = self.visit(node.elt, newnode, assign_ctx)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/astroid/rebuilder.py", line 165, in visit
    visit_method = getattr(self, visit_name)
AttributeError: 'TreeRebuilder3k' object has no attribute 'visit_joinedstr'
```

Answer (score 5):

pylint [does not support](https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/issues/1072) Python 3.6 yet. You'll need to either install pylint and astroid directly from their git repositories, or run it with Python 3.5 or older.

Comment: pip3 had no problem installing it. i'll have to find out how to uninstall and then install it from git

Comment: pip doesn't support any version checking for Python

Comment: It's been over two years since this answer. Is is still true?

Comment: Nope - a pylint/astroid version supporting 3.6 was released on the same day this answer was written.